# DataTable find or if not found insert row

Tags: c#, insert, datatable, row, datarow

I have a DataTable dt with 2 columns. First col (call it CustomerId) is unique and doesn't allow nulls. the second one allows nulls and is not unique.

From a method I get a CustomerId and then I would like to either insert a new record if this CustomerId doesn't exist or increment by 1 what's in the second column corresponding to that CustomerId if it exists.

I'm not sure how I should approach this. I wrote a select statement (which returns System.Data.DataRow) but I don't know how to test whether it returned an empty string.

Currently I have:

```
//I want to insert a new row
if (dt.Select("CustomerId ='" + customerId + "'") == null) //Always true :|
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["CustomerId"] = customerId; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datatable is being populated by a database. I would recommend making the customerid a identity column. That way when you add a new row it will automatically create a new customerid which will be unique and 1 greater than the previous id (depending on how you setup your identity column)

I would check the row count which is returned from the select statement. Something like

I would also use string.Format...

So it would look like this

```
var selectStatement = string.Format("CustomerId = {0}", customerId);
var rows = dt.Select(selectStatement);
if (rows.Count < 1){
  var dr = dt.NewRow();
  dr["CustomerId"] = customerId; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to solve similar problem. You can modify it to fit your needs.

```
public static bool ImportRowIfNotExists(DataTable dataTable, DataRow dataRow, string keyColumnName)
{
    string selectStatement = string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", keyColumnName, dataRow[keyColumnName]);
    DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select(selectStatement);
    if (rows.Length == 0)
    {
        dataTable.ImportRow(dataRow);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Select` Method returns an array of DataRow objects. Just check if its length is zero (it's never `null`).

By the way, don't write such statements in the code directly as in this example. There's a technique for breaching your code's security called "SQL Injection", I encourage you to read the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In brief, an experienced user could write SQL script that gets executed by your database and potentially do harmful things if you're taking `customerId` from the user as a string. I'm not experienced in database programming, this is just "general knowledge"...